# which scope has a bean that is created through a singleton factory bean

Tags: spring, session, scope, singleton, javabeans

I have defined the following beans:

```
<bean id="factoryBean" class="com.example.MyFactory" factory-method="getMyBean"/>

<bean id="myBeanSession" class="com.example.bean.impl.myBeanSessionImpl" scope="session" lazy-init="true">
<aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>     

<bean id="myBeanNoSession" class="com.example.bean.impl.myBeanNoSessionImpl" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true"/>
```

MyFactory.java:

```
public abstract class MyFactory{

public static MyBean getMyBean(){       
    MyBean myBean=null;
    try{
       myBean=(MyBean)Application.getBean("MyBeanSession");         
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
       if (e instanceof IllegalStateException || 
                     e instanceof BeanCreationException) {
        myBean=(MyBean )Application.getBean("MyBeanNoSession");

       } else
            throw e;
    }       
    return myBean;
}
```

factoryBean is a singleton, myBeanSession is session, and myBeanNoSession is prototype.

If no exceptions are thrown, so myBeanSession is created through getMyBean method, which scope has the bean that is created?

In the test that we are doing seems that it is a singleton scope bean, instead of session scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bean will have session or prototype scope, but never singleton.